# Dynamics CRM in low-trust helpdesk scenario

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011

Ok, so imagine a bank has a call-centre filled with low-trust staff. The staff need to provide basic service to customers over the phone. The call centre staff take calls from a customer, ask them certain security questions, and then service the accounts in some way.

Now, from the customer's point of view, the bank is verifying who they are by asking the security questions. This is subtly different from the bank's point of view: It is verifying that the *call centre employee* is talking to the customer.

Why is this difference important? The bank wants to restrict these low trust staff, so they cannot view any details of the accounts until the customer calls them. So a call centre employee can't browse account details of customers that haven't just contacted him and asked for service.

So the question is:
Is this sort of setup possible in Dynamics CRM 2011? How would one go about implementing it? Some level of customization would be OK, but a bespoke application driven from the CRM data is not.

I'm thinking that maybe it's possible to create a custom component that temporarily modifies the user's permissions to a record (and all its children) after answering some security questions. However, I'm not even sure that record-based security (beyond Ownership) is supported in CRM...? I guess one could temporarily assign ownership to the user. Is that wise?

**Please note:** Simply hiding views & find buttons from the GUI isn't the sort of level of security we're looking for here. We're looking to literally restrict the user from accesing the records in question.

Comment: I'm thinking Field Level security might help here, so the call-centre users can still search for customers/accounts, but not see any details until they have gone through the custom security check.

Hmmm. Maybe a Dialog could implement the security check.

Still, it seems like this may be hammering a round peg into a square hole. Also managing field level security on tons of fields/entities may not be much fun.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see a couple of options:

1. Working within the permissions model. This could work. You could have access restricted by default, and then have another entity where you'd enter in the account details, a plugin would run and verify the details, and then share the record to the current user. I'd be a little concerned, however, on how the unsharing would work. What would trigger it? Would there be a process that just runs outside of CRM and unshares records periodically. What if that process fails? We've also had performance issues in the past with this type of model... CRM seems to do a lot of work under the hood every time an individual record's permissions are changed like this.
2. Reassigning the owner, as you suggest. Would multiple users ever need to look at the same data? Does the owner of the record need to be maintained for any other reason (e.g. This is Joe's account because he's the owner).
3. Working exclusively with plugins. You could have a plugin registered on Retrieve and RetrieveMultiple of a record. This plugin could filter out all the details you want to hide from the end user. When the user needs to view the rest of the data, they fill out a form or dialog or something with the data. This data is then included in the Retrieve call for the record. The plugin checks for the hidden data, verifies that it's there and correct, then strips it out and lets the request continue, only this time it retrieves all attributes, and the form populates as expected.

Comment: 1. Ah, ok, I forgot about sharing, this would seem to a better way to give the user temporary access. The unshare could be (in this example scenario) linked to the customer hanging up the phone.

Comment: 2. I guess this is no better than 1, but more restrictive, with respect to multiple user access.

Comment: 3. I think the problem with this approach is RetrieveMultiple can return results as part of a pretty complex query. Relying on a plugin to filter out things the user isn't supposed to see may be very hard - and we could never be sure there isn't another way round the blocks put in place.

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: this answer is based on plenty of CRM 4.0 experience and reading the release notes for 2011.

Short answer: no.

Long answer: yes, but the customisation would be major. The 'easiest' option that springs to mind, is that the authentication process is carried out as a bespoke asp.net page that either a) uses a service account to re-assign an entity to an individual and then returns them to the relevant CRM form, then a plug in that re-assigns it back on saving changes
or
b) has it's own set of forms to that update and retrieve information as a service account, and only do so after answering the security questions.

As an aside, any kind of 'scripted' form is almost impossible in CRM 4.0. I believe 2011 slightly improves on that, but what I've seen is still not encouraging. Using CRM in a contact centre for us has meant investing in a piece of third party form building software and creating bespoke forms that can be launched from CRM and return data via the web services (which are impressively flexible). We only use the CRM interface for viewing historic requests - even most updates trigger one of the bespoke forms.

Answer (score 1):

If I was to implement such a scenario I would create a customer access record (new_custaccess) that is linked to the customer record (new_customer). For this example - keeping it simple - I'm going to assume that the customer has a simple access code they must provide before the bank employee (Operator) can access the record. The access code is stored on new_custaccess in a field (new_secretcode).

Security is that the Operator has no privileges to new_customer and read/update privileges to new_custaccess.

There is a single field (new_secretcodeoperator) on new_custaccess that the operator can update. All other fields are restricted from update (and, if appropriate, read) to the Operator.

When the Customer calls and the Operator searches for the appropriate new_custaccess record. Once they locate the record they enter the Customer provided secret code into the field new_secretcode and do a save.

A Pre-Update query executes on new_custaccess in the context of a user with full privileges (call it MASTER, for fun here.) That plug-in checks to see if the provided code matches the secret code. If it doesn't it throws an error and the Operator can retry. If it does match the plug-in strips the field new_secretcodeoperator from the record, to keep it from saving the value. It also shares appropriate permission on the record new_customer to the appropriate operator.

The Operator now has access to the Customer record (you'll have to decide whether to cascade permissions or share on each record - that decision is beyond this discussion.)

We now need to deal with rescinding permission on the Customer record. I would handle this by having an entity new_customeraccess that is generated by the previous plug-in whenever access is granted to a Customer record. A workflow should be triggered on Create of new_customeraccess that cause new_customeraccess to be updated every 20 minutes (or whatever time the client prefers.)

A plugin is registered on Update of new_customeraccess that fires when the field updated by the workflow is modified. This plug-in will determine - via whatever criteria is decided on by the business - whether to continue sharing or revoke sharing.

I would also create some javascript/html based pop-up from the new_customer ribbon to end sharing by updating a field on new_customeraccess. Provide the Operator with limited Update privs on new_customeraccess via field level security.

This should accomplish what you want without going outside the standard CRM customization model. Not exactly sure of where you draw the line on bespoke but this is probably as close as you'll get to OOTB. A few plug-ins are all the C# you'll need. And the only JavaScript will be for usability, not functionality.

Let me know if you have questions.